# angular 6 patchValue updates the value but not when I submit?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am updating the value of a field on blur making it into a currency value on blur. When I type my value and leave the formcontrol the update on blur works and makes the value (20.00) to ($20.00) or (20.05060) to ($20.00) however when I click the generate form button it console.logs the value as it was before my patchValue. How can I fix that?

```js
export class InvoicesComponent implements OnInit {
  invoiceGeneratorForm: FormGroup;
  subtotalSub: Observable<any>;
  subTotal = 0;
  itemPriceCurrent: Observable<any>;
  prices = [];
  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.invoiceGeneratorForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: [""],
      lastName: [""],
      email: [""],
      itemsArray: this.fb.array([this.getItems()]),
      tax: [""],
      subTotal: [{ value: this.subTotal, disabled: true }],
      invoiceTotal: [""]
    });


  }
 private pushCurrentPrice(index: number){
  const control = <FormArray>this.invoiceGeneratorForm.controls["itemsArray"];
   const currentControl= control.at(index)['controls']['itemPrice'];
   const typeCheck = parseFloat(currentControl.value)||0;
   const subFormatted = this.currencyPipe.transform(
    typeCheck,
    "USD",
    "symbol-narrow",
    "1.2-2"
  );
   currentControl.patchValue(subFormatted,{onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});
   console.log(currentControl);

 }
  private getItems() {
    return this.fb.group({
      itemName: ["", Validators.required],
      itemPrice: [
        "",
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required
        ])
      ]
    });
  }
  private addItemRow() {
    const control = <FormArray>this.invoiceGeneratorForm.controls["itemsArray"];
    control.push(this.getItems());
  }
  private deleteItemRow(index: number) {
    const control = <FormArray>this.invoiceGeneratorForm.controls["itemsArray"];
    control.removeAt(index++);
  }

  onGenerateForm() {
    console.log(this.invoiceGeneratorForm.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected. You are using pipes which modifies your data on client side and do not change the actual value of the data. Pipes are used to process the data. Please read https://angular.io/guide/pipes which might give you more details.

Comment: That makes sense, and that’s what I prefer, I just thought that the patchValue and setValue would eventually change the actual value.

Comment: So I would just apply the same logic on submit

Comment: If you want to change the object (data) itself then you have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Yes but doesn’t patchValue itself change the value of my formControl?

Comment: i might be wrong but i think you are getting confused between the data-binding and client side data formatting. When you are applying pipe (patch), you are not actually modifying the data. did i answer your question or i got it wrong?

Comment: Not sure tbh, I used a currency pipe to modify the data on my client side as an input mask, then I used patchValue to set its value, when the user clicks submit I want the form to submit with the new value at the moment i’m just console.log the value but obviously I will put in the logic for server side code. To confirm, before I accept the answer, patchValue doesn’t actually change the physical value of the formControl?

Comment: It should not, formControl just binds the value and pipe just formats it. Better way to test it, you can try console.log your formControl attributes directly.